# Javascript TypeError: variable is undefined only for accessing index

Tags: javascript

If I write the following code:

```
    f();
    function f(v) {
        var a  = v;
    }
```

The browser gives no warning/error in the console. But if I write

```
    f();
    function f(v) {
        var a  = v['hellp'];
    }
```

Then it throws : TypeError: v is undefined. Although the variable "v" was not defined in both cases. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, you are assigning `undefined` to `a`. This is fine.

In the second example, you are trying to read the `hellp` property of `undefined` (and assign the value of that property to `a`). `undefined` cannot have properties, so you get an error when you try to access a property of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is `undefined` in both case, you can assign undefined to something, but if you try to access a field or invoke a method the error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem to set **a** to undefined (**v** is undefined!), but there is problem to access a variable that is undefined!!!
Think about it! In the first case you only set **a**, but in the second you try to read a property (namely **help**) of an undefined variable!